# bind dig no answer for www

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up a domain.  It works for vumila.com, but not with www.vumila.com.  Here are my files:

db.vumila.com:

```
$TTL    3h
@       IN      SOA     ns1.vumila.com. admin.vumila.com. (
                          3        ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.vumila.com.
@       IN      NS      ns2.vumila.com.


vumila.com.    IN      MX      10      mail.vumila.com.
vumila.com.    IN      A       216.172.176.81
ns1                     IN      A       216.172.176.82
ns2                     IN      A       216.172.176.81
www.vumila.com.                     IN      CNAME       vumila.com.
mail                    IN      A       216.172.176.82
ftp                     IN      CNAME   vumila.com.
```

db.216.172.176

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for 176.172.216.in-addr.arpa
;
$TTL    604800
176.172.216.in-addr.arpa.      IN      SOA     ns1.vumila.com. admin.vumila.com. (
                          3         ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
176.172.216.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      ns1.vumila.com.
176.172.216.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      ns2.vumila.com.

82.176.172.216.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR     vumila.com.
```

when i dig www.vumila.com i got this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> www.vumila.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 8352
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.vumila.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
vumila.com.     505 IN  SOA ns1.launchpad.com. anb.hotmail.com. 2014122502 7200 7200 172800 38400

;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 15 18:48:19 CST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

any help please

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem with your `serial` number.

In your live DNS zone the serial number is `2014122502`. But in your new zone it is `3`. Serial numbers can only be incremented; a serial number lower than the previous one will be ignored, along with all the records in the zone.

Whenever you change one or more records in the zone, always change the serial number to a number larger than the previous one.

It is a common convention to use the date of the change along with some extra digits as the serial number, and this seems to be what was done previously:

```
2014 Year
12   Month
25   Day
02   The second of two changes made this day
```

By this convention, you can change the serial to `2015011601` and if you always follow it, the serial will always be larger than it was previously.

Comment: i did it, but still not working

Comment: @anb You'll have to wait for the TTL to expire. Check again in three hours.

Comment: I checked it right now, still not working

Comment: Where did you make these changes? None of your nameservers reflect the changes and they all still show the old serial.

Comment: I did it when you answered me first time

Comment: may it reads from another files???